# How to fully change package name in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-package-managers

For example currently I have package name like **com.test.hello.company** & I want to change it to **com.test.company** only. So How can I change & move the files in all these directories com.test.hello.company without any problem.

Comment: probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/2850044

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)

Comment: try ctrl + shift + R

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click project package
- Select Refactor
- Click on Rename
- In the pop-up dialog, click on Rename Package instead of Rename Directory
- Enter the new name and hit Refactor
- Click Do Refactor in the bottom
- Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes